# Rewrite rule to make php page loaded by a direcory url structure?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^test    test.php    [NC,L]
```

this allows me to access the page via:

`http://www.example.com/test` and `http://www.example.com/test.php` but how can I prevent  `http://www.example.com/test.php` from being accessible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a 403 `forbidden error` page when the `/test.php` uri is direct accessed,you can use this rule :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ - [R=403,L]
```

If you want to redirect `/test.php` to the new uri `/test` use the following :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /test [L,R]
```